# Why does Shamir secret sharing appear to need ordered shares?

Tags: python, numpy, cryptography

The implementation of Shamir secret sharing in this code, only generates the original image if the shares are provided in consecutive order (ex: [2,3,4]) and won't work in any other share order (ex: [2,4,6] or [4,1,3]). However, Shamir secret reconstruction does not require the shares to be in any order, then why does this fail?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange as lag
import os

def polynomial(img, n, k):
    '''
        Generate lagrange polynomial of degree k-1
        f(x) = c1(x^k) + c2(x^k-1) .... + secret (mod prime)
        prime > secret
    '''
    coef = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 251, size = (img.shape[0], k - 1)) #Coefficients should not exceed value of prime number chosen
    gen_imgs = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        base = np.array([i ** j for j in range(1, k)])
        base = np.matmul(coef, base)
        imgValue_ = (img + base) % 251
        gen_imgs.append(imgValue_)
    return np.array(gen_imgs)

def reconstruct(imgs, index, k):
    '''
        Reconstruct image using share index values for k shares
    '''
    print("Shares: ", index)
    assert imgs.shape[0] >= k
    x = np.array(index)
    dim = imgs.shape[1]
    img = []
    for i in range(dim):
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            print("Reconstructing pixel ", i, " of ", dim, " pixels")
        y = imgs[:, i]
        poly = lag(x, y)
        pixel = poly(0) % 251
        img.append(pixel)
    return np.array(img)

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pathPrefix = path.split('.')[0]
    os.makedirs(pathPrefix, exist_ok=True)

    img_flattened, shape = util.read_image(path)
    gen_imgs = polynomial(img_flattened, n = n, k = k)
    to_save = gen_imgs.reshape(n, *shape)
    for i, img in enumerate(to_save):
        Image.fromarray(img.astype(np.uint8)).save(pathPrefix + "/share" + "_{}.jpeg".format(i + 1))
    
    #Secret reconstruction
    shareIndex = list(map(int, input("\nEnter the index of shares to reconstruct: ").split()))
    origin_img = reconstruct(gen_imgs, shareIndex, k = k)
    origin_img = origin_img.reshape(*shape)
    Image.fromarray(origin_img.astype(np.uint8)).save(pathPrefix + "/reconstructed_image.jpeg")
```

The read_image function has the following definition

```
def read_image(path):
    '''
        Reads image from file and converts it into numpy array in greyscale
    '''
    img = Image.open(path).convert('L') 
    img_array = np.asarray(img)
    return img_array.flatten(), img_array.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

The image pixels appear to be deconstructed in a particular order, so it follows that it needs to be reconstructed in the same order.

I think you need to decouple the image encryption from the key sharing. Encrypt the entire image using a single key and then encrypt that key again via SSS into unordered shares.